# Writing in NSUserDefault and .plist failed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, nsuserdefaults

I'm having trouble getting some informations written in my .plist, and NSUser Defaults Files.
For the .plist i've already posted but, nothing seems to be wrong:

[How to update an array set into the .plist dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744160/how-to-update-an-array-set-into-the-plist-dictionary)

And for the NSUser Default, i'm doing something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *userSettings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[defaults objectForKey:@"userSettings"]mutableCopy]];

[userSettings addObject:userSettingsArray];//adding an array into my userSettingsArray (declared higher in the code)
[defaults setValue:userSettings forKey:@"userSettings"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I was wandering, is there any option in Xcode allowing , or not, the user to write into the app folders?

I'm a little stuck here

Thank you for your help,

Tim

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Seems right so far...

Comment: What leads you to conclude that your setting isn't being stored? The code looks rather confused; the `mutableCopy` is entirely redundant and you're building an array of arrays?

Comment: @Mario: The array didn't get copied, when i want to retrieve the informations stored, the array is empty.

Comment: @Tommy, i need to store multiple users informations (array of arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:
I entered the datas from the IBOutlet like this

```
[self.tempUserSettings insertObject:self.firstName atIndex:1];
```

instead of this:

```
[self.tempUserSettings insertObject:self.firstName.text atIndex:1];
```

so the datas were wrong, and so and so.....

Thank you for you help, learned a lot from those .plist and NSUserDefault

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[defaults setObject:userSettings forKey:@"userSettings"];
```

instead of

```
[defaults setValue:userSettings forKey:@"userSettings"];
```

Comment: Nope, i can't get the array writen in the UserDefaults. this is my code to get the array out of NSUserDefault: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSArray *userSettings = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"userSettings"]];
        _tempUserArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:userSettings];

Comment: Try adding an NSArray to User Defaults instead of an NSMutableArray. If this doesn't work either, you can always convert your array into NSData and then saving it to user defaults. If you do this, you will always have to encode/decode the data before using it. You can find how this is done in Apples documentation.